# Display standard home page component in visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, home-page-component

Is it possible to display the standard home page component such as tasks, calender and dashboards on a visualforce page?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding - Dashboard snapshot in VF page. Read the SFDC Help pages to ["Embed Report Charts in Visualforce Pages"](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_analytics_vf_charts.htm). and the [relevant visualforce tag page.](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm) Please note this feature is only generally available from the Spring '14 release.

```
<apex:page>
    <analytics:reportChart reportId=”00Oxxxxxxxxxxxx”></analytics:reportChart>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: <apex:page>
<analytics:reportChart reportId=”00Oxxxxxxxxxxxx”></analytics:reportChart>
</apex:page>

Answer (score 0):

They're actually always displayed if you don't put sidebar="false" in the apex:page parameters. But that's probably not what you mean?

Since these are not part of the VF library I don't think you can add them to a VF page. They're not that complex, though, so most of it you can probably rebuil from scratch in VF if you really want to.

Comment: #Cryst maybe you can provide some additional feedback to help me improve the answer. Or post a better one.