# Is there a way to place a standard homepage component on a visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, home-page-component

I've been re-doing the homepage for my organization, and one of my requirements is that the standard components of the homepage are displayed on the visualforce page used. My problem is that there's no way to directly show a standard homepage component on another page. Has anyone found a solution to this that does not involve rebuilding the component yourself, or an external app?

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29589/display-standard-home-page-component-in-visualforce

Comment: From my experience, i dont think you can do that.. I dont have any offical documentation to support it. I really would like to be wrong though :)

Comment: I looked into using the <analytics> tag, but the problem with that is I lose formatting of the dashboard entirely. As far as I know, there's no way to get the locations of the charts on the dashboard, which makes this tag much more useful for a single chart then a dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree to @Prady and @DashboardReport that it's most likely not possibly to do this with an official method.

However a workaround could be to use PageRef.getContent() on your original homepage url and parse the html for the components you want and inject them back into your Visualforce page. This is a very hacky and ugly approach an could lead to odd side effects - but possibly your last resort to do it at all.